# Unable to create disk partition from free space on Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I had partitioned my computer with two partitions, C: and D:, with D: used as recovery. All was fine until 5 months later, when my laptop (Samsung RV511 running Windows 7 Home Basic) crashed (I assume, because of a virus). I recovered it using my backups. However my D: drive is not showing up in Windows Explorer.

In Disk Management, C: drive (which is used as the System Partition) is showing, and then next to it is "free space" that I suspect was supposed to be the D: partition. When I right-click and create a new volume, it doesn't complete successfully because it says my operating system does not support dynamic disks. Please help. I want to recover this space; it's a good 100GB.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Protip: Be sure to spellcheck.

Comment: Sorry Dennis, we were editing at the same time O_o feel free to rollback if you think your version is better...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to extend a partition instead of create a new one. A "Dynamic Disk" allows windows to create partitions that have odd shapes and arrangements across the disk, such as jumping over another partition or having an end point before its start.

Make sure when you right click on the empty space to select "New simple volume"

Conversely: are you sure that's not just the 100 MegaByte SYSTEM partition that Windows creates for itself? if so, you cant have that portion.